# Requirements for Kodi addon auto-updates - sees update but doesn't retrieve it

Tags: repository, auto-update, add-on, xbmc, kodi

I can manually install the updated plugin over the older version and the older version will see that an update is due within Kodi (by noticing new `addons.xml.md5`) but it never progresses further.

*I didn't make a separate repository plugin zip - haven't read anything saying that it is specifically required. Answering this would be very helpful and may be the problem. It seems unnecessary however given that Kodi does still see that it needs an update.*

I have the `addon.xml` file set up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon
    id="script.name"
    version="3.0.1"
    name="3"
    provider-name="4">

    <requires>
        <import addon="xbmc.python" version="2.1.0"/>
    </requires>

    <extension point="xbmc.python.script"
        defaultresolution="720p"
        defaultresolutionwide="720p"
        library="default.py"/>

    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
        <platform>all</platform>
        <minversion></minversion>
        <summary lang="en">summary</summary>
        <description lang="en">description</description>
        <website>site</website>
        <source>trunk</source>
    </extension>

    <extension point="xbmc.addon.repository"
               name="Add-on Repository for 3">
        <info compressed="true">http URL for addons.xml</info>
        <checksum>http URL for addons.xml.md5</checksum>
        <datadir zip="true">http URL for zips</datadir>
    </extension>
</addon>
```

Going with plugin id = `script.name`, within the zips directory is a folder named `script.name` containing a single zip file named `script.name-3.0.1.zip`. Inside the zip file is another folder named `script.name` which contains addon.xml and the other plugin contents.

The full path is `zips\plugin.name\plugin.name-3.0.1.zip\plugin.name\addon.xml`.

The above is what I have seen used for other addons as far as I know. What is the proper repository/directory configuration? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug that prevents several addons referencing the same repository in their `addon.xml`. So if you repo contains more than one addon, having a separate dedicated repository addon is necessary. Or create several repos for each addon.

Also, starting from Kodi 17 Krypton, md5 checksum files are mandatory for zipped addons. That is, if you have `addon.foo.bar-1.2.3.zip`, then you need to create `addon.foo.bar-1.2.3.zip.md5` alongside it. It's a plain text file containing md5 hexdigest for the respective zip.